# unable to match or replace in recursiveTagParse return string

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm currently working on making a nested tag extension, where the parent tag (in my case `<tabs>`) needs to be able to influence the contents of the child tag (in my case `<tab>`). I've tried doing this by just running `$parser->recursiveTagParse($input)` where `$input` is the contents of the `<tabs>` tag, but in the returned string, it seems to be impossible to match for anything. To test this in the most basic way possible I did the following:

add to LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once "$IP\\extensions\\Test\\Test.php";
```

Create Test.php in its Test directory with:

```
<?php
$wgAutoloadClasses['Test'] = __DIR__ . '/Test.body.php';
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'Test::init';
```

Create Test.body.php with:

```
<?php
class Test {
    public static function init( &$parser ) {
        $parser->setHook( 'testfoo', array( 'Test', 'firstTag' ) );
        $parser->setHook( 'testbar', array( 'Test', 'secondTag' ) );
        return true;
    }

    public static function firstTag($input, $attr = array(), $parser, $frame) {
        $newinput = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input);
        return preg_match_all("/ /", $newinput);
    }

    public static function secondTag($input, $attr = array(), $parser, $frame) {
        return htmlspecialchars($input);
    }
}
```

and finally, put the following on a page on the wiki:

```
<testfoo>three spaces out here<testbar>and four more spaces here</testbar></testfoo>
```

This should make the final output for  be `7`, since there are 7 spaces in the output string. The problem is that this instead returns `3`, the amount of spaces that are outside the `<testbar>` tag.

What I'd like to know is if it is possible at all to match and/or replace the *results* of parsing the nested tag (so what the nested tag outputs), and if that is not possible, is it possible to make the `<testbar>` tag behave differently when nested inside a `<testfoo>` tag?

---

I've also tried adding a `PPFrame` as second argument to the part of `$parser->recursiveTagParse($input)` to attempt making it possible to detect nesting, but the documentation for PPFrame is so unclear that I have no idea what I need to do. What I do now, based on [what the documentation says](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/interfacePPFrame.html#a0d6afda4c8f359ee25e8ac896127e0ca) is this:

```
    public static function firstTag($input, $attr = array(), $parser, $frame) {
        $newframe = $frame->newChild(array('nested'=>'true'), $frame->getTitle(), 0);
        $newinput = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input, $newframe);
        return preg_match_all("/ /", $newinput);
    }
```

But that causes errors. What it says when I do that is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\hiddenpath\w\includes\parser\Preprocessor_DOM.php on line 984
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, null given, called in C:\hiddenpath\w\extensions\Test\Test.body.php on line 10 and defined in C:\hiddenpath\w\includes\parser\Preprocessor_DOM.php on line 984

But I've got no idea what I need to do to fix this. Do I need to make my first argument a special object? And if so, why does the documentation say I need to put an array as first argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering this question myself with an alternative because there were no other answers*

The way I managed to get the result I wanted is to just give up on the original first part of the question: "*What I'd like to know is if it is possible at all to match and/or replace the results of parsing the nested tag (so what the nested tag outputs)*" and just move along to the second part, "*if that is not possible, is it possible to make the  tag behave differently when nested inside a  tag*".

The way I did this is by defining a variable within the class, and then changing that whether I was doing a `recursiveTagParse` on the content of a  or not. The code in Test.php would then be:

```
    public static function init( &$parser ) {
        $parser->setHook( 'testfoo', array( new self(), 'firstTag' ) );
        $parser->setHook( 'testbar', array( new self(), 'secondTag' ) );
        return true;
    }

    function firstTag($input, $attr = array(), $parser, $frame) {
        $this::$nested = true;
        $newinput = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input);
        $this::$nested = false;
        return preg_match_all("/ /", $newinput);
    }

    function secondTag($input, $attr = array(), $parser, $frame) {
        if ($this::$nested) {
            $output = 'Display for when nested'.$input;
        } else {
            $output = 'Display for when not nested'.$input;
        }
        return htmlspecialchars($output);
    }
}
```

That way I was still able to make the `<testbar>` tag behave differently when inside the `<testfoo>` tag. I'm not sure if this is the way it's supposed to be done, but it works.

PS: I've also ignored the `$frame->newChild()` code, since that didn't seem to work, and no clear documentation or examples were available.